# Nested for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes, function-definition

I'm trying to print out prime numbers using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prime_check(int number);

int main(){
    int x;
    printf("Number of choice\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    prime_check(x);
    return 0;
}

int prime_check(int number){
    int count = number;
    for (number>=0; count>=0; --number ){
        for (number>=0; count>=0; --count){
                if (number % count !=0){
                    printf("# %d\n ",&number);
                }
        }
    }

return number;
}
```

The following is the output I get no mater the input: # 6422272

Being a self-learner, I would like can get any relevant guidance you may find appropriate to both the above issue as well as the path I'm on with C.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. The initialization part of your loops don't make sense. What is `number>=0;` supposed to mean? Hint: It doesn't!

Comment: How is your function supposed to work at all? What is meaning of the return value? What is meaning of the output? Also you should enable more warnings in your compiler. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`. This should result in some warning regarding parameter type mismatch in `printf("# %d\n ",&number);` This should probably be `printf("# %d\n ",number);` but the whole print is not related to prime numbers at all.

Comment: Your inner loop runs until `count==0` which causes trouble when used in `if (number % count != 0)`.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: Do you mean to use [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)? You'll need to allocate more memory.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the first expressions in the for loops

```
for (number>=0; count>=0; --number ){
     ^^^^^^^^^
        for (number>=0; count>=0; --count){
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

do not have an effect. They are discarded.

The outer loop has only one iteration (provided that initially number is not negative) because after the inner loop the value of the variable `count` is negative.

Moreover this if statement

```
if (number % count !=0){
```

can invoke undefined behavior when count will be equal to 0.

In this call of printf

```
printf("# %d\n ",&number);
```

you are trying to output the address of the variable number using the conversion specifier d for objects of the type `int` that invokes undefined behavior.

Even if you will write correctly

```
if (number % count !=0){
    printf("# %d\n ",number);
}
```

then it does not mean that the current value stored in  number is a prime number. It only means that the current value of number is not divisible by the current value of count.

And the function always returns the value

```
number - 1
```

where number is considered as the initial value of the parameter (provided that it is not negative) or the initial value of number itself if it was negative.

So the function entirely does not make a sense.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime_check( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        printf( "There are no prime numbers in the range 0 - %u\n", n );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Prime numbers in the range 0 - %u:", n );

        for ( unsigned int current = 2; current <= n; ++current )
        {
            int prime = current == 2 || current % 2 != 0;
            
            for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= current / i; i += 2 )
            {
                prime = current % i != 0;
            }
            
            if ( prime )
            {
                printf( " %u", current );
            }
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n;

    printf( "Number of choice: " );
    if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) == 1 )
    {
        prime_check( n );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Number of choice: 50
Prime numbers in the range 0 - 50: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code, but the one most directly responsible for the number you are seeing is in this line:

```
printf("# %d\n ",&number);
```

By putting & before `number` you are asking the computer to print the memory address where variable `number` is stored, instead of the actual value of that variable.

It seems every time you ran your program so far, this variable was created at the same address, and that is what you saw in the output.

Remember - `printf` is the opposite of `scanf` it needs values not addresses (unless you are trying to print a string a.k.a. null terminated array of characters).

Your second problem is how you use `for` loops.

```
for (initialization; condition; change)
```

You put a condition `>=` in an initialization part, where an initial value should be assigned.
If you don't want to assign any initial value, you can leave that part empty and put semicolon ; directly after the bracket (.

Then, in the change part, you decrement a different variable then the one you are testing in condition part, so potentially your loop may never end.

```
for (number>=0; count>=0; --number )
```

You test `count` but you decrement `number` so `count` may never change and your program will run for ever.

Also, you loose the value of the original number passed to your function, by using it as loop index, but perhaps this is what you want?

Which brings us to the biggest problem in your code:
It does not check for primes.

All your code tries to do is print a bunch of remainder values (modulus), and then return some value that will be ignored.

If you want to actually check if a number is prime, start by writing out what steps would you, as a human, take to check it manually on paper.

Once you have this pseudo code, you should be able to create correct C code.